# Apache restrict access to payara

Tags: apache-2.4

I need to restrict access to specific location in payara application.
Is it possible in apache2.4 ?
I tried using

```
<VirtualHost *:8181>

    <Location "/dir">
        Require all denied
        Allow from 192.168.0.0/24
    </Location>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

But this does not work for some reason.
It is linked to sites-enabled, so this should not be problem, but I am still able to access this directory, even from other network than 192.168.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing directives from 2.2 and 2.4 which won't yield good results.

Do not use Allow/Satisfy/Deny/Order any more.

```
<Location /dir>
    Require all denied
    Require ip 192.168.0.0/24
</Location>
```

Comment: Still did not help. Could there a problem if it is a SSL connection. No errors in log, nothing.

Comment: SSL communication must succed before any http communication is made yes, but you are showing a virtualhost with port 8181, are you sure you are using SSL? If in doubt try with curl "curl -v httpX://yourserver.example.com:port/path".